# Rewrite URL case

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following URL: http://sitename.com/?parameter_1=data&parameter_2=data

it always remains the same with the same data. I want it to be converted into the following URL: http://sitename.com/most-popular

I believe it is quite simple to do it from .htaccess but I am not familiar with rewrite rules.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed URL of what it can be and what you want.

Comment: http://sitename.com/?parameter_1=data&parameter_2=data that is an exact url and wont be changed... sitename and 2 static parameters to make a call to popular posts

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand what you mean, you could try this

```
RewriteRule ^most-popular/?$ ?parameter_1=data&parameter_2=data [L]
```

Comment: Strange but going to sitename.com/most-popular returns not found. Are you sure the code is right?

Comment: make sure you also add `RewriteEngine On` to the beginning of your .htaccess file

Comment: RewriteEngine is on but still nothing. It is wordpress setup and permalinks are working fine. Anything else i could do?

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_rewrite on the server? For instance, create a test.html file and see if this works: `RewriteRule ^/mytest/?$ /test.html [L]`